# Validation for numeric but not equal to 0 in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use DataAnnotations in mvc4 for valid value only for numeric but greater than 0, Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use the [`[Range]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value must be greater than 0")]
public int Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: *It has not worked* is not a very precise problem description. At least not one that allows me to help you further. Because this approach has worked perfectly fine for me. Maybe if you explained what specific problems you encountered with the Range attribute we could discuss further.

Comment: I have written this code, but not working                                                                     [Required]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value bigger than {1}")]
        public virtual int EstimateHours { get; set; }

Comment: What does **not working** mean??????????? You get an compile-time error? You get a runtime error? You don't get the expected result? Your computer crashes? Apples start falling from the sky?

Comment: error message is not showing if i press enter after enter 0 in this field

Comment: I want to ask one question more, can we show or share image here?

Comment: You could start a new question. As far as this one is concerned, you should consider closing it by accepting an answer. And yes, you could upload an image.

Comment: ya sir, this helped me, but this is not working at other page for same fields. I am sending model, controller and views to explain, please see

Comment: Model is :
public class WorkOnTicketModelBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EstimateHours { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value bigger than {0}")]
        public int WorkedHours { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }

        public User AssignedToUser { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public class WorkOnTicketCreateModel : WorkOnTicketModelBase
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "AssignedToUser")]
        public int AssignedToUserId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AssignedUser { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ticket Status")]
        public int TicketStatusId { get; set; }

        public TicketStatus TicketStatusVal { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TicketStatus { get; set; }

    }

Comment: public class TicketDetailModel : TicketModelBase
    {
        public WorkOnTicketCreateModel WorkOnTicketCreateModel { get; set; }

        public Ticket ParentTicket { get; set; }
        public List<Ticket> Childs { get; set; }  

    }

    public class TicketModelBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
       [Required]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value bigger than {0}")]
        public int EstimatedTime { get; set; }
    }

Comment: And Contoller is
        [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Details(TicketDetailModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = this.nhSession.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var ticketObj = this.nhSession.QueryOver<Ticket>().Where(t => t.Id == model.Id).SingleOrDefault();
                var workOnTicket = new WorkOnTicket();
                    workOnTicket.Ticket = ticketObj;                    
workOnTicket.WorkedHours = model.WorkOnTicketCreateModel.WorkedHours;